# Why the codeigniter don't save SVG image?

Tags: php, codeigniter, svg, codeigniter-2

My program saves extension file gif, png and jpg in my folder normal, but, it doesn't save SVG image.I wonder why it doesn't save?

My function in libraries:

```
function uploadImage($idImage, $local){

    $config['upload_path']   = $local;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'svg|gif|png|jpg';

    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('upload', $config);
    $CI->upload->do_upload($idImage);

    return $CI->upload->data();
```

}

OBS: $idImage is a var with name of ID HTML and it isn't ID of database!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change/Add the allowed types in config/mimes.php

```
'svg'   =>  array('image/svg+xml'),
```

That should work, didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

Your config/mimes.php should contain both svg, svg+xml. Update your code to this in config/mimes.php

```
'svg'   =>  array('image/svg+xml', 'application/xml', 'text/xml','image/svg'),
```